# SQL query to find matching groups of records between two tables

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I have two tables:

```sql
Table "Shares":

+---------+
| share 1 |
+---------+
| share 2 |
+---------+

And table "Valuations"

+-------------+---------+
| valuation 1 | Share 1 |
+-------------+---------+
| valuation 1 | Share 2 |
+-------------+---------+
| valuation 2 | Share 1 |
+-------------+---------+
| valuation 3 | Share 1 |
+-------------+---------+
| valuation 3 | Share 2 |
+-------------+---------+
```

I would like to know if there is an SQL Server (T-SQL) query that starts from the "Shares" table and returns only those valuations containing both of the "share" records ("Share 1" & "Share 2")  - an inner join between the two tables would also return "valuation 2" in the result set and that is not something that I want.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Just a confirmation by someone more knowledgeable than me, would INTERSECT give me the result that I want?

Comment: Use a `GROUP BY` and a `COUNT DISTINCT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the column name in `shares` and `valuations` is `share`, can group by valuation and set the condition in the `having` clause:

```
select valuation
from valuations
group by valuation
having count(distinct share) = (select count(*) from shares)
```

If you want all the rows from valuations:

```
select * from valuations
where valuation in (
  select valuation
  from valuations
  group by valuation
  having count(distinct share) = (select count(*) from shares)
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dd5ff93a13bed33ab97833d39848efb8).

Comment: The thing is, I require the valuations instead of the shares i.e, the result table should be four rows, two for valuation 1 and two for valuation 3

Comment: Would this do the trick?  select v.valuationic
from #shares s inner join #valuations v
on v.shareic = s.shareic
group by v.valuationIC
having count(*) = (select count(*) from #shares)